# Find the longest word in a string using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to find the longest word in a varchar2 (in a string) in an Oracle query. In some situations I would split the string into separate words in a table, then aggregation functions could solve it (e.g. once I have max(length(my_field) I can track down the longest word(s)).

But in this case I don't have that luxury. So I need to calculate the longest word in a string without aggregation.

I found a way to use REGEXP_REPLACE to find words longer than N characters. And that's not bad. But I don't see a way using regex or any other functions to find the longest word.

Here's a simplified version of what I used to find words over 4 characters:

```
select 
  regexp_replace(
    ' a  cd  efg  hijk  lmnop  qrst  uvw  xy  z '
    , '([^[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]{1,3}[^[:alnum:]])'
    , ' '
    , 1
    , 0
  ) x
from dual;
```

But how could I return only the longest word(s)?

Comment: i can only think of using substring as for regex it's hard.

Comment: splitting the string into words may be your only option if you plan to do it without PL/SQL.

Comment: This is unclear. If more than one word are tied for longest, do you want to return them all? What if your string has all words of the same length, let's say 7 characters - how do you propose to "return" them, if not in separate rows? So don't you have to break the string apart anyway? And what do you mean by "don't have that luxury"? Which luxury?

Answer (score 0):

Editted: Sorry I didn't fully read your intention. So in your case for some reason you couldn't use aggregate functions, the following solutions is just for reference. Best regard!

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 
        regexp_substr(' a  cd  efg  hijk  lmnop  qrst  uvw  xy  z ','[^ ]+', 1, level) col
    FROM 
        dual
    CONNECT BY 
        regexp_substr(' a  cd  efg  hijk  lmnop  qrst  uvw  xy  z ', '[^ ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
    col 
FROM 
    tmp
WHERE 
    length(col) = (SELECT MAX(length(col) ) FROM tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need a way to extract the longest words (one or more) from a given string without using any table to store data.

If so, this could be a way:

```
with test(s) as ( select ' a  cd  efg  hijk  lmnop  qrst  uvw  xy  z LMNOP' from dual)
select word
from (
        select regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as word,
               rank() over ( partition by 1 order by length(regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) desc) as rank
        from test
        connect by regexp_instr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level) > 0
     )
where rank = 1

WORD
----------
lmnop
LMNOP
```

The inner query uses a commonly used method to split strings and then uses `rank` to evaluate every row based on the length of its word:

```
with test(s) as ( select ' a  cd  efg  hijk  lmnop  qrst  uvw  xy  z LMNOP' from dual)
select regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as word,
       rank() over ( partition by 1 order by length(regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) desc) as rank
from test
connect by regexp_instr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level) > 0

WORD             RANK
---------- ----------
lmnop               1
LMNOP               1
hijk                3
qrst                3
efg                 5
uvw                 5
xy                  7
cd                  7
z                   9
a                   9
```

The external part simply filters the result to only get the rows with the words at top rank, that is the longest words.

This works in case you have more than one word with the top length, and is based on the assumption that input strings are in the format you posted; for example, if you added a comma to separate the words, it would be considered as a part of the word.